# Is there a physical reason behind zeta regularization?

Tags: mathematical-physics, regularization

Does there exist a reason why zeta regularization always works?

I mean for the Casimir effect the series $ 1+8+27+64+\dots=1/120 $ gives the correct result. The same holds for $ 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+\dots =-1/12 $ in string theory. For functional determinants the values $ \zeta(0) $ and $ \zeta' (0) $ also appear.

So, as far as we know could we generalize this result so that every time we see the series $ 1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n+\dots $ in any physical theory, we give this series the value $ \zeta (-n) $?

I think the answer is negative, then why should zeta regularization work for some $n$ values but not in the most general case?

Comment: you've got to read [this Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/) article

Comment: The unambiguously rigorous computation, where you consider the difference between the vacuum without the two plates and with the two plates where you have the summation over the allowed modes, will in some cases be equivalent to a zeta function regularization where you only look at the mode sum for the vacuum energy between the plates and regularize that summation using analytic continuation involving the zeta function.

Comment: tao's article is just pure mathematics not physics :D

Comment: @JoseJavierGarcia Tao's article establishes the equivalence between the hard cut off(or asymptotic expansion) and analytical continuation(zeta regularization). The former has definite physical meaning- for higher enough energy, the theory is not valid. So one should not sum to infinity but to some high energy cut off.

Comment: @Jose: "Physical reasons" are often nothing more than unstated mathematical assumptions.